# SQLPLUS TRIM and COLUMN formatting

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, sqlplus

I have just executed a PL/SQL procedure and have the output:

FirstName               LastName      Role        Quote

what I am wanting to do is use trim and column formatting to output the information like below so that first and last name appear on one row and then role and quote on the next row which are to be separated by a |

FirstName LastName

|Role    | Quote     |

I am not sure how to do this and any help on this would be appreciated

Comment: `FirstName` and `LastName` on one row, then `Role` and `Quote` on another row? Could you give a realisitic example using that formatting?

Comment: Yes FirstName and LastName on one row then below this Role and Quote separated by a |

Comment: SQL naturally doesn't work in that way. My recommendation is to keep all four fields in one row, then deal with formatting in your application.

Comment: it is a requirement of the project I am currently undertaking to do so, is there a way this can be done? if not how do I shorten the gap on the one row as they are currently separated by several blank spaces as well as add a | at the end of each field

Comment: @Dems: Can fields be concatenated and a carriage return added?

Answer (score 0):

If this is output from a PL/SQL procedure - which I assume means that it is accomplished with calls to DBMS_OUTPUT - then SQLPlus column formatting commands will have no affect on it.  You would need to modify the procedure to do the output the way you want it.

If this was the output of a SELECT statement then I believe you could use the `fold_after` or `fold_before` options on the `column` statement to do what you want.

Comment: Yes it dos include dbms_output, how would I modify the procedure to format it?

Comment: Can't be sure without seeing the code.  But since you want to change from one line of output to two, you most likely need to replace one call to `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` with two separate calls.

Comment: Thankyou, never thought of that! however using column formatting and trim would be more ideal if this at all possible?

Comment: dbms_output.put_line( row.firstName || ' ' || row.lastName || ' ' || row.roleName || ' ' || row.quotechar);